# Typescript type: Object with static/fixed keys and dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How do I create a typescript type for an object, where I can have a fixed set and dynamic set of keys? For example:

```
export type APIOMethods = 'getA' | 'getB' | 'getC';

export type item = {
  divId: string;
  role: string;
  [key: K in APIMethods]?: any;
};
// Not working ↑↑↑ 

export type item = {
  divId: string;
  role: string;
  [key: APIMethods]: any;
};
// Not working ↑↑↑ 

// the object could look like this:
{divId: '', role: '', getA: {}} OR 
{divId: '', role: '', getB: {}} OR 
{divId: '', role: '', getC: {}}
```

- Typescript Playground Link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCAFAkgWWDACwgBMBnOAXjgHIBzfNauAHxvpgCEnW78BhagG4AUMNCRYCZKijAAdsWBQAIgEMYqrDGABbSnADewuHGIBLAG5ZiALjikYUM3NoiTUCABtgdh05ducADaANbAiHYA0nDO6Nh4hCSkALoA-HaqcogiAL4iokA)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution: using a mapped object type**:

```
export type item = {
  [key in APIMethods]?: any;
} & {
  divId: string;
  role: string;
};
```

After fiddling around with the code more inside of [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), the editor ended up making a suggestion to use a mapped object type when I had type this earlier

```
export type item = {
  divId: string;
  role: string;
  [key: APIMethods]: any; 
  ^ An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.ts(1337)

};
```